# How can I repair a worn and rusting dishwasher rack?

Tags: dishwasher

I have a GE dish washer, the bottom rack coating has come off, some of the tines, and now my dishes have rust spots on most of them. I tried to replace the rack at GE, but the part has been discontinued and the replacement rack is too big. I wonder if I can tape rusted parts with water proof tape.

Comment: Where specifically are they worn? Tine ends? bottom bars?

Comment: That possibly extra comma is confusing. Is it "bottom rack coating has come off" + "some of the tines" - i.e., rack & tines have problems, or is it "bottom rack coating has come off some of the tines" - i.e., the tines on the bottom rack are what have the problem. Commas are important!

Answer (score 9):

There are products designed specifically for this, [like this one](https://amzn.to/39q5Bep):

[image: Dishwasher Rack Repair Kit]

I haven't tried it - I actually have a kit but never got around to it...

I definitely would not use tape because if it comes off during a wash cycle and clogs the drain you have a real mess. The racks (doesn't matter what brand) vary by model. Even when you can get replacements, the cost is a significant portion of the cost of a new dishwasher.

Comment: I've used that exact kit on a rack where the tine ends had broken open and there were occasional other worn spots. Worked pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

You could try [Plasti-Dip](https://plastidip.com/).

Paint-able or sray-able or a Dip liquid.

They have some  for just your problem. [ReRACK](https://plastidip.com/our-products/rerack/).

Comment: I feel like Plasti-Dip would come off immediately in a wash cycle. Considering how easy it comes off when just washing the car.

Comment: I would guess that plastidip would hold much better when wrapped around a wire/rod than when spread over a flat surface.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly use self-amalgamating tape for this, although I don't know what sort of temperatures this will stand up to.

The simplest thing may be just to clean the loose rust off the tines with gentle sanding, and cover them with several coats of nail-varnish. If there is a large area to do, use something like hammerite.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loyal to your dishwasher brand, used dishwashers are very cheap, and you may consider replacing your own, or upgrading to a better model.  Don't spend much money on repair.